Determine the intermediate fields of the splitting field $\Omega^{X^{5} - 2}_{\mathbb{Q}} \subset \mathbb{C}$.
Question: Let $f = X^{5} - 2 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. Determine the Galois group of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and determine all the intermediate fields of the splitting field $\Omega^{f}_{\mathbb{Q}} \subset \mathbb{C}$. Give explicit generators of the intermediate fields.
My attempt: I have already shown that $\text{Gal}(\Omega^{f}_{\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb{Q}) \cong \text{Aff}(\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z}) = (\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z}) \rtimes (\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z})^{*}$ with the operation on the right group defined as $(a, b) \cdot (c, d) = (a + bc, bd)$.
I am struggling with determining the intermediate fields (and their generators). I thought about using the main theorem of the Galois theory by first explicitly determining all subgroups of $\text{Aff}(\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z})$, and then determining the corresponding fixed fields. But I am struggling with determining the subgroups in the first place. I don't even know if this is the right approach for this question.
If anybody could help me out with the last part I would greatly appreciate that!

The Galois group of $x^5-2$ is the Frobenius group $Fr_5\cong C_5\rtimes C_4$ of order $20$. Every subgroup of $Fr_5$ is isomorphic to one of the following groups:
$$
Fr_5,C_4,D_5,C_5,C_2,1.
$$
For the subgroup lattice, see for example here.
This gives the diagram of intermediate fields, by Galois correspondence - see for example this duplicate:
Intermediate fields of Gal($x^5-2$, $\mathbb{Q}$)
